# Java Object with optional fields

Tags: java

I have one scenario , please have a look

Sentence can be :

> String Subject + String Verb + String Object
>
> String Subject + String Verb + String Adverb+ String Object
>
> String Subject + String Verb + String Adjective+ String Object
>
> String Subject + String Verb

I want to create a Sentence class object.

```
  Sentence s = new Sentence();
    s.setSubject();
    ...
```

Now , I can keep all fields in Sentence class, but **I want to ensure that no field must be null.**
    I want to create any type of sentence from fields that **I initialize** where i create object.

```
eg: 
Sentence s = new Sentence();
s.setSubject();
s.setVerb();
s.setObject();
s.getValue(); // will return sentence value as S+V+O as I have set SVO

Sentence s = new Sentence();
s.setSubject();
s.setVerb();
s.getValue(); // will return sentence value as S+V as I have set SV
```

and so on ... can I do something like this in java.

Basically, **I want to avoid uninitialized fields and nullpointers.**

**EDIT**

Please note that if i leave fields empty ie "" or null , sentences formed will be like

"I am **null** to school." or (verb is **null**) .

"I **am to** school" (verb is **empty**) .

So, please consider this scenario before answering.

Comment: You can set all fields to an empty string by default.

Comment: There's nothing like _uninitialized fields_ in java. All fields will be initialized with their default values (which is `null` for `String`). So you can check for `null` values and construct the string in `getValue()`.

Comment: i dont want to check each and everywhere, basically this object will be used all over my application , so i want to ensure that that strings are not empty or null

Comment: @swapyonubuntu, I guess I misunderstood... Do you mean you don't want to get a `null` or `empty string` when calling `getValue()`.

Comment: yes else sentence will be like "I am null to school." or "I am to school"... which is wrong.......

Comment: in case some one tries to create a sentence with say only subject, verb and adjective and forgets objet, you want to throw some exception or you trying to show compile time error ? (which I doubt would be possible)

Comment: The user will not forget....here problem is not about forgetting , here problem is about building object with initialized fields only.

Comment: thn as suggested in my answer, you can throw exception if subject and verb are not initialised before forming the sentence (as these are must), if user is not forgetting about rest of the fields, thy will be empty and sentence will be formed just by subject+verb, only problem arise if user sets few fields and forgets other, which you saying is not possible, so whats the issue ?

Comment: The builder pattern is *BY FAR* the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will prefer using a builder pattern, make the usage clearer for the end user and avoid mistakes

```
    Public class Sentence {

        private String subject;
        private String verb;
        private String adjective;
        private String object;

    //package private to ensure no one can call it outside package, canbe made pvt as well
        Sentence(String subject, String verb, String adjective, String object) {
            this.subject = subject;
            this.verb = verb;
            this.adjective = adjective;
            this.object = object;
        }

        public static class SentenceBuilder{
            private String subject;
            private String verb;
            private String adjective;
            private String object;

            private static final String EMPTY = "";

            private String sanitizeInput(String input){
                if (input==null){
                    return EMPTY;
                }
                return input;
            }

            private String validateInput(String input){
                if(input==null || input.isEmpty()){
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("cant be null or empty"); 
                }
                return input;
            }

            public SentenceBuilder(String subject, String verb) {
                this.subject = validateInput(subject);
                this.verb = validateInput(verb);
            }

            public SentenceBuilder adjective(String adjective){
                this.adjective = sanitizeInput(adjective);
                return this;
            }

            public SentenceBuilder object(String object){
                this.object = sanitizeInput(object);
                return this;
            }

            public Sentence build(){
                return new Sentence(subject,verb,adjective,object);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
//sample usage            
Sentence sentence = new SentenceBuilder("subject","verb")
                    .adjective("adjective")
                    .object("object")
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer is correct, it goes in the right direction. However, I'd also create sub-builders, so that a sentence with a wrong structure cannot be created.

Comment: @coder thanks ! Works like a charm. @ Federico Peralta Schaffner what do you mean by sub builder ? can you give an example so I can use it!

Comment: The example above works, but if we instead call `new SentenceBuilder("subject", "verb").build()` then `adjective` and `object` will be null in the returned `Sentence` object. To avoid this, the `sanitizeInput()` calls could be moved into the `build()` method or the fields of `SentenceBuilder` could be initialised to empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the fields are null, and create a sentence based on that information:

```
if (s.getSubject != null)
 {
  //do something
 }
if (s.getVerb != null)
 {
  //do something
 }

etc.
```

Comment: Please note if i set  subject="" and I call getValue .....  sentence will be "I am to school"... which is wrong..

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: my sentence class can give me any sentence .. ie SVO or SVOA ... whatever fields are initalized by calling.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you don't want malformed sentences. That is, a sentence without a subject and a verb.

So, you can modify your constructor to get `subject` and `verb` and throw `IllegalArgumentException` if either of them is `null` or `empty`.

```
public Sentence(String subject, String verb) {
    if (subject == null || subject.isEmpty()) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Subject?");
    }
    // Same as above for verb.

    this.subject = subject;
    this.verb = verb;
}
```

This way, an object cannot be created without a `subject` or a `verb`.

Answer (score 0):

In ***Java***, there is no convenient way can do this, You need it's Option, use `getOrElse` to get the default value.In Scala, it has [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) class do this thing.

I think you can use HashMap in Java to do this thing.

```
public class Test {
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        data.put("subject", subject);
    }

    public void getSubject() {
        data.getOrDefault("subject", "your_default_value");
    }

    public void setVerb(String verb) {
        data.put("verb", verb);
    }

    public void getVerb() {
        data.getOrDefault("verb", "your_default_value");
    }

    public void setObject(String object) {
        data.put("object", object);
    }

    public void getObject() {
        data.getOrDefault("object", "your_default_value");
    }
}
```